# how does python pick the ports to be used in sockets

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, port

i cant understand why each time python chooses different port for me even i have specified a static port ,for example last output was :
     Server waiting for connection...
     Client connected from:  ('127.0.0.1', 52480)
here is the code for both client and server side ,just don't know how python does that and also if there a way to impose on python to use port i have set

> **server**

```
 import socket
 import threading

 def sendMsg(conn):
 while True:
     msg = input()
     conn.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

 def recvMsg(conn):
    while True:
    msg = conn.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode('utf-8'))

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
   socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8000))
   server_socket.listen(5)
   print('Server waiting for connection...')
   client_sock, addr = server_socket.accept()
   print('Client connected from: ', addr)
   obj1 = threading.Thread(None, target=sendMsg, args=(client_sock,))
   obj2 = threading.Thread(None, target=recvMsg, args=(client_sock,))
   obj1.start()
   obj2.start()


  obj1.join()
  obj2.join()
  client_sock.close()
  server_socket.close()
```

> **client side**

```
import socket
import threading

def sendMsg(conn):
  while True:
    msg = input()
    conn.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))


def recvMsg(conn):
  while True:
     msg = conn.recv(1024)
     print(msg.decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock_addr= ('127.0.0.1',8000)
  client_sock.connect(sock_addr)
  obj1 = threading.Thread(None, target=sendMsg, args=(client_sock,))
  obj2 = threading.Thread(None, target=recvMsg, args=(client_sock,))
  obj1.start()
  obj2.start()

  obj1.join()
  obj2.join()
  print('Socket is closed!!!')
  client_sock.close()
```

Comment: Your server has a fixed port (8000), but your client doesn't explicitly bind to one so is assigned a random port above a certain number - this is the same for most socket implementations on most systems. You can make your client use a fixed port by `bind`ing it to one like you do for your server.

Comment: alright i got it bro ,thank you for your help :D